# Getting nearest line to point with virtual layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, query, virtual-layer

I have a streetmap and the position of hundred sensorlocations. I am currently trying to calculate the nearest line for each point. I have already done it with the nnjoin plugin. But now I want to do this with a virtual layer. For this, I followed the tutorial: https://pigrecoinfinito.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/qgis-minima-distanza-tra-punti-e-linee/

But unfortunately, I could not get it to work because I am very new to SpatiaLite. 
To create the virtual layer, my approach looks like followed:
[image]

If I want to test this query, I am getting the following error note:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

---

I have know tried it with renamed tables, but I am still getting the same error message.

Maybe something more is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here (maybe you have spotted a bug) is in the memory layer (maybe a processing output?). It contains an SQL keyword into the field definition `&field=from:string&field=to:string` which is not correctly parsed from the virtual layer provider. So a workaround could be to change fields name for the memory layer named `Reprojiiziert`. Or save to file the memory layer and using that in your query.

Also, please you feel free to file a ticket in the QGIS bug tracker [0] as this is something that affects the upcoming 3.0 version as well.

[0] - https://issues.qgis.org

Answer (score 0):

Spatialite table names can't contain capital letters unless they are quoted:
then retry changing them to `"EVIS_Stat_Sensorik"` and `"Reprojiiziert"`or use only lowercase chars naming them.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately, I am still getting the same error .